# MySQL only get Varchar from Database

Tags: mysql, c#

I have a MySql Datbase which looks:

```
Item    CREATE TABLE `Item` (
        `ItemID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `ItemName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `Description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
        `Date` date NOT NULL,
        `Responsible` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `Done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `Velocity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `Inspector` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `WorkbenchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY `PK` (`ItemID`),
        KEY `ItemID` (`ItemID`)
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

User    CREATE TABLE `User` (
        `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `UserName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY `PK` (`UserID`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=83 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
        UserInWorkbench CREATE TABLE `UserInWorkbench` (
       `WorkbenchID` int(9) NOT NULL,
       `UserID` int(9) NOT NULL,
        KEY `WorkbenchID` (`WorkbenchID`,`UserID`),
        KEY `UserID` (`UserID`),
        CONSTRAINT `UserInWorkbench_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`WorkbenchID`)                 
        REFERENCES `Workbench` (`WorkbenchID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE              
        CASCADE, CONSTRAINT `UserInWorkbench_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`)       
        REFERENCES `User` (`UserID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Workbench   CREATE TABLE `Workbench` (
            `WorkbenchID` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `WorkbenchName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE KEY `PK` (`WorkbenchID`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I can Insert without anny problems, I can also get Varchar Values, but I can´t get any other Datatypes like Date Int etc.

For Example:

This is running fine:

```
MySqlCommand getUser = new MySqlCommand("Select  ItemName From Item", connection);
```

But this:

```
MySqlCommand getUser = new MySqlCommand("Select  ItemID From Item", connection);
```

Get´s the Exception:

> {"Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length."}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Why can´t I get Int,Date etc. values ?

Comment: Is this a C# error or a MySQL error? If it is a C# error then it is probably off topic here. If it is a C# error, like it appears, then the bug is in your de-serialization code not the database.

Comment: That's a C# error.

Comment: I think the problem is that the int values arent unsidned is that possible ?

Comment: Does the exception come from `new MySqlCommand()`, or some later use of `getUser`?

Comment: How you execute the command `MySqlCommand `?

Comment: Please show all the code around these calls. This is an error coming from somewhere else, not in the creation of the MySqlCommand

Comment: The Exception comes from Execute Command an I found out that the problem is that I have no attribute in the Int or date values when I use unsigned int as Attribute all is working finde